# How can I find total amount of RAM my system has using C

Tags: c

is there a way to find out the total amount of RAM my system has using C?
I am on Ubuntu 12.04. I need to write an application in C that should ideally query the total amount of RAM during run time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Linux, this is available from `/proc/meminfo`.  Example:

```
MemTotal:       16469432 kB
MemFree:          792136 kB
MemAvailable:   15201832 kB
Buffers:         5806244 kB
Cached:          8637760 kB
...
```

Just open this as an ordinary file, and parse the contents.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if there was some function in C library that could do this for me.

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest way is to use procfs (see Dietrich's answer).

However, for more details about the hardware (RAM, CPU count, speed, model numbers, misc other devices) you can extract tons of info from dmesg:

```
dmesg | grep Memory
```

You can use the C stdlib popen() to read from dmesg if you have privs, and parse all sorts of info. I have used this for a monitoring system like Spong to extract as much information as possible about the node. You can even monitor it live for feedback from hardware / device commands you issue (dmesg | tail -f).

Keep in mind dmesg isn't always available, depending on privs.

Answer (score 1):

@abc This documentation can help you. http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html

Answer (score 1):

Only way to get physical RAM available is by using BIOS calls if you don't want the OS to do it for you.
All the information you need http://wiki.osdev.org/index.php?title=How_Do_I_Determine_The_Amount_Of_RAM&redirect=no

Answer (score 0):

you can use **top** command will show cpu usage memory usage ,etc